# partial derivative for gradient descent

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I'm going through this [video](https://youtu.be/XdM6ER7zTLk?list=PL2-dafEMk2A7YdKv4XfKpfbTH5z6rEEj3&t=1890) to understand gradient descent.

This is the error equation:

$$error = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - (mx_i + b))^2$$

where m =slope, b = intercept.

How are the partial derivatives with respect to m and b are calculated ? Please show all the intermediate steps.

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial m} = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N -x_i (y_i - (mx_i + b))$$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial b} = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N - (y_i - (mx_i + b))$$

Comment: Why don't you show us some work, like, compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\,\big(y_i-(mx_i+b)\big)^2$?

Comment: @Batominovski ok, so since its for m -  x,y and b would be constants. expanding the square, would be $$ y_i^2 - 2y_i(mx_i + b) + (mx_i + b)^2$$. Expanding the square and then applying partial derivative on each, we get $$ 0 - 2y_i x_i + 2x_im + 2x_ib + 0 $$

Comment: Yes, then compare the result you just got with the second-to-last equation in your question.

Comment: its close. but it seems i messed up somewhere. when i factor out $-2x_i$ I would get $ -2x_i(y_i - m - b)  $. Why am I getting m instead of mx ?

Comment: Because you should have $2x_i^2m$ not $2x_im$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836811/partial-derivative-of-the-slope-in-straight-line I have seen similar thread. Hope this helps