# Partial Derivative of the Slope in Straight Line

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I'm a noob in mathematics and I'm now studying basic Maths for Machine Learning. Now I'm learning the equation of straight line `y = mx + b`. For the gradient descent process for the best fit line, I've learned that we need to use Partial Derivative for b (y-intercept) and m (slope).

In derivative equation for (m) slope, I am lost how the **line1** is formulated to **line2** in the following diagram.

[image]

I know the basic concepts of Calculus and Derivative. I'm lost how this Trinomial square is calculated from the first one to second one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos, I will follow your suggestion in my future posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac d{dm}\left[\frac1{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n(mX_i+b-y_i)^2\right]&=\frac1{2n}\cdot\frac d{dm}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(mX_i+b-y_i)^2\right]\\\text{(put derivative into summation)}&=\frac1{2n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\frac d{dm}(mX_i+b-y_i)^2\right]\\\text{(chain rule)}&=\frac1{2n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\left[2(mX_i+b-y_i)\cdot\frac d{dm}(mX_i+b-y_i)\right]\\&=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left[(mX_i+b-y_i)\cdot X_i\right]\end{align}$$